# backspace behaviour changed to ^H in bash shell after sometime

Tags: bash, shell, backspace

My backspace is deleting letter backward as expected in my bash shell after logon. But for unknown reason, occasionally, after a while of use, it instead outputs ^H. This is annoying. I have to log off/on again to correct its behaviour.

Do you know how I can find out the cause and fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Some programs may mess up with the terminal configuration, usually commands that control the terminal like text editors, `screen`, vms over stdio, *etc.* Run `reset` and then `stty erase`<kbd>backspace</kbd> and see if fixes it for you.

If you do a typo while typing these commands, do not delete the whole line , just type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and it will work like <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

Comment: Depending on how "smart" one's shell is trying to be, it might be necessary to precede the backspace after `stty erase` with a ctrl-V.

Comment: what does 'reset' do here?